# Multiple thread not working correctly in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I create parallel process and DataTable `dtUser` have two rows, it should create two browser:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dtUser.AsEnumerable(), items => 
            OpenBrowser(items["user"].ToString(), items["pass"].ToString()));

Lapsoft_OneDriver browser;
public void OpenBrowser(string username, string password)
{
    browser = new Lapsoft_OneDriver(Browsers.Chrome);
    browser.GoToUrl(link);
    browser.FindElementById("txtUserName").SendKeys(username);
    browser.FindElementById("txtpassword").SendKeys(password);
}
```

It create two Chrome process but only first process running line code block:

```
browser.GoToUrl(link);
browser.FindElementById("txtUserName").SendKeys(username);
browser.FindElementById("txtpassword").SendKeys(password);
```

The second process only initializes new browser and not do anything.

If I change this line:

```
browser = new Lapsoft_OneDriver(Browsers.Chrome);
```

to

`var browser = new Lapsoft_OneDriver(Browsers.Chrome);`

It's working.

But another method continues to use variable `browser` to execute other code.

So, I must declare global variable `Lapsoft_OneDriver browser` out of a function to use in another method use it.

My problem is:

Why using `Lapsoft_OneDriver browser;` it create two Chrome process but only first process active, it will insert to `browser.FindElementById("txtUserName")` two values of variable `username` and second process not do anything?

**Updated**:

When to change the code, I have any problem.

I will add more code of frmMain_Load:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thread = new LThread();
    thread.StartedEvent += new LThread.startDelegate(AllCaseProgram);
    numLog = int.Parse(dtSetting.Rows[0]["num_Log"].ToString());
}

int numProcess;
private void AllCaseProgram(object args)
{
    try
    {
        switch (numProcess)
        {
            case 0:
                Parallel.ForEach(dtUser.AsEnumerable(), items => Start(items["user"].ToString(), items["pass"].ToString()));
                break;
            case 1:
                ClickCart();
                break;
            case 2:
                Result();
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (browser != null)
            browser.Cleanup();
        numProcess = 0;
        AllCaseProgram(null);
    }
}
```

At event of button `StartProgram()_Click`. I start Thread like: thread.Start();

You said: should be add this function to my program.

```
public static void Start(string user, string pwd)
{
    var test = new frmMain();
    test.OpenBrowser(user, pwd);
    test.ClickCart();
}
```

My update question is:

Seem function `Start(string user, string pwd)` should be change to function `AllCaseProgram` include all switch case.

And variable `numLog` in frmMain_Load have values = 3. In function `test.ClickCart()` I also use this variable but values auto change to 0.

Have any issues with code? Thanks.

And `LThread` class is:

```
public class LThread : BackgroundWorker
{
    #region Members
    public delegate void startDelegate(string ID);
    public event startDelegate StartedEvent;
    private static int RandNumber(int Low, int High)
    {
        Random rndNum = new Random(int.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));

        int rnd = rndNum.Next(Low, High);

        return rnd;
    }
    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        StartedEvent(RandNumber(100,10000).ToString()); //put whatever parameter suits you or nothing
        base.OnDoWork(e);
        e.Result = e.Argument;
    }
    BackgroundWorker bwThread;
    // Main thread sets this event to stop worker thread:
    public Boolean bwIsRun;
    int m_time_delay = 10000;
    Delegate m_form_method_run;
    Delegate m_form_method_stop;
    Form m_type_form;
    #endregion

    #region Functions

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            bwIsRun = true;
            this.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch { }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            bwIsRun = false;
        }
        catch { }
    }
    private void StartToListen(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(m_time_delay);
            if (bwIsRun == true)
            {
                m_type_form.Invoke(m_form_method_run);                    
            }
            else
            {
                BackgroundWorker bwAsync = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                if (bwAsync.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: Make the variable browser local to OpenBrowser method, easy, not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encapsulate your state for each test run. That way you'll have a class that has the responsibility the start a browser, execute one or more actions, while keeping all the required state belonging to a single run private for just one instance, while you can have a many instances as you like (if resources permit).

```
// this is NOT a winform, this is a new and seperate class ...
// don't try to mix this with an WinForm, that will fail
public class BrowserTestRunner
{
     // only this Test instances uses this browser
     Lapsoft_OneDriver browser;

     private void OpenBrowser(string username, string password)
     {
         browser = new Lapsoft_OneDriver(Browsers.Chrome);
         browser.GoToUrl(link);
         browser.FindElementById("txtUserName").SendKeys(username);
         browser.FindElementById("txtpassword").SendKeys(password);
         // you probably want to click on something here
     }

     // some other test
     private void ClickCart() 
     {
         browser.FindElementById("btnCart").Click();
     }

     // add other actions here

     // this starts the test for ONE browser
     public static void Start(string user, string pwd)
     {
         var runner = new BrowserTestRunner();
         runner.OpenBrowser(user, pwd);
         // wait for stuff, check data, prepare the next steps
         // for example
         // runner.ClickCart();
         // other actons here
     }
}
```

Now you can create as many Test class instances as you like, while each instance of the class manages its own internal state, without interfering with other instances:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(dtUser.AsEnumerable(), items => 
        BrowserTestRunner.Start(items["user"].ToString(), items["pass"].ToString()));
```

If you want to start that from your backgroundworker do:

```
private void AllCaseProgram(object args)
{
    try
    {
        switch (numProcess)
        {
            case 0:
                Parallel.ForEach(
                    dtUser.AsEnumerable(), 
                    items => BrowserTestRunner.Start(items["user"].ToString(), items["pass"].ToString()));
                break;
            case 1:
                ClickCart();
                break;
            case 2:
                Result();
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (browser != null)
            browser.Cleanup();
        numProcess = 0;
        AllCaseProgram(null);
    }
}
```

By all means: don't start the main form again. Just separate your WinForm from the code you use to operate the browser. That does mean that you have to move the code that interacts with the browser to the BrowserTestRunner. Don't try in keeping the logic for your selenium stuff in the WinForm class because that is doomed to fail. As you are already experiencing.

Comment: I tried your code. It was not working. I don't create new `class Test`, I using direct `class frmMain`. Typical, the first process will execute code at `ClickCart`, but your code both process stopped after complete `OpenBrowser`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you keep using your own class  without instantiating it. If you say *I don't create new class Test* that is exactly your problem. I've edited my code so you'll no longer be able to call OpenBrowser or Clickcart. You can only call the static method `Start` and that is all you need.

Comment: `var test = new Test();` will fail. I apply in real code, and my class is `public partial class frmMain : Form`. Should be `var test = new frmMain();` but when I call `test.OpenBrowser` it calls again. I updated my question to clear more. Because I think class `Start()` of your working correct but I call from case when it more complex.

Comment: If you stop mixing your logic to drive to browser with your form, everything start to work. You need to have 2 classes at least, your form and the Test class

Comment: Can you add more code? Function `Start()` working but it break `AllCaseProgram` function. And I can't access to variable was assign in `frmMain_Load`.

Comment: I have done what I can. But you don't seem to fully understand what that you need to create separate classes

Comment: In function `Start()` you run both `OpenBrowser()` and `ClickCart`. It will fail in my case. Function `AllCaseProgram()` in this case isn't meaning because in the program must run `OpenBrowser()` first if condition in this method is true it can switch to case 1 or case 2. Are you know my opinion? Like your code, I need to delete all code in function `AllCaseProgram()` only keep line `Parallel.ForEach(.....` and in function `Start()` at the switch case.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you need. I have done my best.

Comment: thank you very much. You very enthusiastic. I grateful for that. I will try fix this.

Answer (score 1):

What you got here is sort of a race condition. You got two threads not getting along when handling a single field in the class. Your problem is *only* that you don't have sufficient space to store all the browser instances you require.

What happens is basically that the first thread enters the method, creates a instance of the chrome browser and stores it in the variable. Then the second thread enters the function and does the same thing. But it also stores the instance in the same variable. Now the first thread continues and goes to a link. But the instance it is working with is already replaced by the second thread. And so on. This may happen with the threads the other way around or the overlapping may happen after more lines where handled. But it is bound to go wrong.

The way to resolve it, is as you noticed to make the variable local by adding a `var`. This way both threads are working with distinct variables.

Now you said you need the variable in another function. The question is: Do you need both? Do you need only one? Do you need a specific one?

In case you need only one, you just store the variable in the global variable by adding a line like this in your function:

```
this.browser = browser;
```

So it would look like this in total:

```
Lapsoft_OneDriver browser;
public void OpenBrowser(string username, string password)
{
    var localBrowser = new Lapsoft_OneDriver(Browsers.Chrome);
    localBrowser.GoToUrl(link);
    localBrowser.FindElementById("txtUserName").SendKeys(username);
    localBrowser.FindElementById("txtpassword").SendKeys(password);
    this.browser = localBrowser;
}
```

I changed the name of the local browser variable, so it gets clearer what variable is used. Do note that either one of the created browsers could end up in the variable.

In case you need a specific one you have to determine if you have the correct one and store the result after this.

If you need both you have to store them in a list. The namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent` offers lists that can be handled by multiple threads at once.

Comment: Your answer looks very nice and this exactly I meet. I need to only one variable. I tried to add: `this.browser = browser;` in method `OpenBrowser`. Can you add more code?

Comment: I checked and seemed only first Chrome process continues to execute code using `browser` at other function. At second process it still not working.

Comment: What do you expect the second instance to do? Just remain open?

Comment: Yes, it was open. But it can't use variable `browser` in another method. In method `OpenBrowser` I call `GetIframeVideo` but the second instance doesn't know `browser`.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I added some code how to publish your browser variable. I still not not totally get why you open two browser windows and only work with one. But that is yours. ;-)

Comment: In another method I using Thread.Sleep(x) will have one process fails.